# angularjs ui-router issue with resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm creating an app using angularjs and angular-ui-router for state based routing. I have several routes in my app, but one is the one that demands attention. The state is defined as follows

```
state('profile', {
            url: '/profile',
            controller: 'ProfileController', //controller on a different file
            resolve: {
                user_profile: ['User', function (User){
                    return User.getProfile(); //returns a json object
                }]
            },
            templateUrl: 'profile.html'
        })
```

The getProfile code:
getProfile: function(){
                var d = $q.defer();

```
            $http.get('/profile')
                .success(function(res){
                    if (res.status == 'success'){
                        d.resolve(res);
                    } else {
                        d.reject();
                    }
                })
                .error(function(reason){
                    d.reject(reason);
                });
            return d.promise;
        }
```

Now in my controller file I have the following code:

```
.controller("ProfileController", ['$scope',function($scope,user_profile){
    console.log(user_profile);
}]);
```

The thing is that resolve should inject the resolved results in the controller, on a parameter named user_profile(because in the keys of the state definition I used user_profile) and the injected dependency has a value of undefined as stated by the console.log call.

I have debugged my code and the service that fetches the user profile on the server works really well, so, no problem in there. Even if I use an object return on the user_profile resolve key the error remains.

The other thing is that if I, on the state definition set the controller property to a function defined in the state definition then the dependency is injected with the correct value, but I don't want this, I want the dependency injected on the defined controller no on a inline controller as well.

So, what can be happening here?

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: where's the code for `getProfile` ? Do you also have `ng-controller` in template?

Comment: I don't have the ng-controller directive on my template because on the state definition I expose the controller for the state. The code of getProfile() is very simple. I have edited my question and added the code

Comment: right, just checking about controller because using both is not an uncommon mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the strict DI syntax for angular (array of strings for dependency names, with the function as the final parameter of the array), but you have not specified the `user_profile` dependency in the array.

E.g.

```
.controller("ProfileController", ['$scope','user_profile',function($scope,user_profile) { console.log(user_profile); }]);
```

Comment: No need to, because if you specify the user profile_dependency on the array then angularjs throws an exception saying that the user_profile provider was not found. resolve injects the dependency automatically.

Comment: @asolenzal no, you need all injections in the array and in proper order

Comment: @asolenzal you are incorrrect. If angular is throwing that error then that is a clue to what your actual issue might be...

Comment: right, you are right my friend, that resolved the problem.... +1 and answer mark for you